# Value error : invalid literal for int() with base 10 in hackrank

Tags: python, python-3.x

Below code is working fine locally where as it is failing in hackerrank any modification we need to do ??

```
n=int(input())

for i in range(n): 
    for y in range(i+1):
        print("* ",end="")
        
    print("")
```

Comment: What's the full error message? It should contain the input string that caused the error.

Comment: Presumably hackerrank doesn't provide any input to `input()`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not validating the value that is going into the `int()` function.
You can replicate the error with this snippet:

```py
input_value = 'Some String'
int(input_value)

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Some String'
```

In your case I believe you would want to validate the argument provided by the user in `input()`.
One alternative would be:

```py
valid_input = False
while not valid_input:
    input_val = input()
    try:
        # Try to cast the value to an int
        n = int(input_val)
        # If it succeeds save and exit the loop.
        valid_input = True
    except ValueError:
        # If it could not cast it to an int
        print('Invalid input -- please enter a number')
```

And once you have your input, you can proceed with your code:

```py
for i in range(n): 
    for y in range(i + 1):
        print("* ", end="")
        
    print("")
```